# How to subtract every instance of an item in list b from list a

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have the two below lists in Python:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
b = [2, 4]
```

and I want to create a function like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
y = [2, 4]

def array_diff(a, b):
    # CODE HERE

print(array_diff(x, y))   # Output = [1, 3, 3, 3]
```

I originally tried this solution:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    for item in a:
        for i in range(len(b)):
            if b[i] == item:
                a.remove(b[i])
    return a
```

but this code returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

I tried changing the code but it was of no success. I tried finding solutions here but nothing popped up.

Comment: You're modifying a list while iterating... Have you tried building and returning a new list instead? Also, there's no "mathematical subtraction" happening

Comment: Do you mean remove from the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
y = [2, 4]

def array_diff(a, b):
    return [i for i in a if i not in b]

print(array_diff(x, y))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

If you will use the `array_diff` by iterating over it *(no more than)* once, like this:

```
for i in array_diff:
    print(i)
```

you can increase the efficiency b utilizing the `yield` keyword:

```
x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
y = [2, 4]

def array_diff(a, b):
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            yield i

for i in array_diff(x, y):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
3
3
3
```

Comment: For large lists, `b = set(b)` before the return might improve this a bit